# While paused at a breakpoint in chrome, can chrome pause in other breakpoints reached by commands issued the console while paused?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, javascript-debugger

I am debugging Javascript in Google chrome. Execution is paused at an endpoint and I enter a statement in the console, e.g., hidder.hideImage(). I would like to know if its possible to stop in a break point that is in the hideImage function and how to do it? After the execution path triggered by the console is done, I would like to remain stopped at the first break point.

Comment: You just need to find the `hideImage` function within the sources tab, and add a breakpoint inside it. You can then step through it line-by-line.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat I did. But the breakpoints doesn't stop if I am already paused at some other breakpoint (I am triggering a commend from the console while paused at some other endpoint).